# iOS: Copy property

Tags: ios

I couldn't get the right answer for this question. If it is found duplicate, please make it duplicate with the right reference link.

I wanted to know, what are the ways the reference count is incremented. I know, alloc/init and retain increases the reference count, does 'copy' also increases the reference count to '1' ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`copy` creates a new object which is, as the method name suggest, a carbon copy of the receiver (well in fact it depends of the implementation of the `copy` method in each class, but that's the aim of the method anyway).

So in fact it does not really "increase the reference count of the by 1" but it rather create a new object, with a refcount of 1 as any newly allocated object, and make it have the same property / ivar values as the original.

So imagine you have a `Person` class with the properties `name`, `surname` and `age`, if you needed to implement the `copy` method yourself it would look sthg like this:

```
-(id)copy
{
    // Create a new instance
    Person* mycopy = [[Person alloc] init];
    // Make it an exact copy of the original
    mycopy.name = self.name;
    mycopy.surname = self.surname;
    mycopy.age = self.age;
    // and return that copy
    return mycopy;
}
```

*Note that in this case, if you modify the copy later, the original is not modified, because it is a different instance.*

With this principle, the original object does not have its refcount incremented by one, but you have a new object whose refcount is one (as if you just did alloc/init to create this new object yourself) and you still have to release or autorelease it at some point yourself (if you are not using ARC). That's why calling `copy` on an object obey the same rules as `retain` or `alloc` regarding the need to call `release` or `autorelease` to balance the refcount at some point

---

Note that there is some exceptions / special cases, especially for some classes that are known as "immutable", like `NSArray` or `NSString`. In such cases, it is reasonable to thingk that making a copy (aka a different object instance) that is a clone of the original, whereas the original cannot be modified, is not really efficient, and can be optimized.

So in cases like `NSArray` and `NSString` and some other, the `copy` method may simply implemented to do a simple `retain` as the behavior will be the same as you can't modify the original (and neither the copy) because these are immutable classes by nature.

Of course, the implementation of `mutableCopy` (to get an `NSMutableArray` from an `NSArray` for example) do a real copy and not a simple retain, and the implementation of the `copy` method in the mutable subclasses like `NSMutableString` and `NSMutableArray` do a real copy too, but for the case that request an immutable copy of an immutable object, the point of allocating a different instance is generally useless and memory-consuming and is thus implemented the same as a `retain`.

But all this probable optimization does not change neither the behavior (because the classes are immutable) nor the memory management policy (as you still need to `release` the object returned by `copy`)

Comment: Ok, Basically what i understood so far about 'copy' is its copying as it is and duplicating another object. But, newly duplicated object doesn't create new address, rather both (actual and duplicate) pointing to the same location in memory. So, when using 'copy' is NOT increasing the reference count to '1'.

Comment: See my edit about optimizations generally done in cases of immutable classes like `NSString`/`NSArray`/`NSDictionary`/etc. In cases of immutable copy of immutable objects, the `copy` method simply does a `retain`, because in that case it will behave the same (as you can't modify neither the original nor the copy, no need to have separated instances). So in such special optimized case, calling `copy` will be a synonym of calling `retain`. But you don't have to bother about this optim & implementation detail, because that does not change the behavior nor the memory mgmt rules to apply.

Comment: Ok, finally i understood from your very detailed explanations (thank you so much for that!) 'copy' increase the reference count to '1'. So, there are three ways such as alloc/init, retain and copy reference count can be increased by '1'.

Comment: Yep. Well you should in fact for the `copy` case better say that the sum of the refcounts for the original object + the object returned by copy are 1 more than the refcount of the original object before `copy`. Either the object returned by `copy` is the same as the original, but with its refcount incremented by one (because of the optimisation in the immutable objects case), or the `copy` method return a new, independent instance (for mutable cases) with a refcount of 1 while the original object does not has its refcount modified. So at the end the total refcount sum is one more, yes.

Comment: But note that all of this (wether it returns a real copy or optimize it by returning itself after incrementing the refcount) is really implementation details. In practice you shouldn't bother about these optimization details and keep the encapsulation of the concept in mind. So the ONLY think you should know is that the aim of `copy` is to returns a copy of the object, and that you need to `release` this copy (wether it's an actual copy or not in reality doesn't matter) the same way you would do to balance a `retain` or `alloc`. The rest is only internal implementation details of each class.

Comment: _PS : I see you're new to StackOverflow, so If you think that my answer solved your question, don't forget to accept it (by clicking the green tick next to it) to mark your question as solved for other users to know._